# Clear NSTableView Content

Tags: objective-c, macos, nstableview

I have an `NSTableView` that gets filled with data from the program. I have a Reset button that, amongst uses for other parts of the program, *should* clear the `NSTableView`'s data.

However, I have absolutely no idea how to do this. I'm still learning Obj-C.

Comment: Can you add the relevant code?

Comment: Sure. Pastebin: http://pastebin.com/WK6JtHeF

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove objects one by one from an NSTableView by calling `removeRowsAtIndexes:` ([documentation here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/applicationkit/classes/NSTableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSTableView/removeRowsAtIndexes%3awithAnimation%3a)) and then calling `reloadData` on the NSTableView.

If you want to clear all of your data, you'll need to clear your datasource (usually an NSArray that you provide the table with for its data) and then call `reloadData`. To clear your datasource, if it is an NSDictionary or NSArray, call `removeAllObjects` on the NSDictionary or NSArray. Here's an example of what you might do:

```
[myDataSourceDictionary removeAllObjects];
[myTableView reloadData];
```

Take a look at [Apple's documentation on NSTableView](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/applicationkit/classes/NSTableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html) too.

Comment: I used an Array Controller, so I adapted your code by accessing the Array Controller's NSArray:

[[arrayController content] removeAllObjects];
[tblLapsAndTimes reloadData];

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

To any who may find this question from Google:

If you are using an Array Controller to add things to the table, simply access the NSArray inside the controller and remove objects from it, then reload the table.

```
[[yourArrayController content] removeAllObjects];
[yourTableView reloadData];
```

Thanks to RazorSharp for helping me get on the right track!

Answer (score 0):

Delete the data source and call `[tableView reloadData];`

Comment: ...how do I delete it? What data source are you referring to? I'm using an Array Controller and NSMutableDictionary if that helps.

Comment: @user2616830 Please take a look at my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18602402/814730)

Comment: @user2616830 set the NSMutableDictionary to nil or removeAllObjects, then ask the NSTableView to reloadData.