# Clear table using a button in objective-c

Tags: objective-c, nstableview

I'm trying to clear all from a table using a button.  Basically reset the table.  I use the following to remove one slice at a time but how do I clear all from the table?  Thank you in advance!

```
- (IBAction)handleRemoveSliceTapped:(NSButton *)sender {
NSInteger selectedRow = [self.sliceTable selectedRow];
if (selectedRow < 0) {
    return;
}
if ([self.sliceTimes count] == 0)  {
    return;
}

NSIndexSet *removalSet = [NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:selectedRow];
[self.sliceTable removeRowsAtIndexes:removalSet withAnimation:NSTableViewAnimationSlideUp];
[self.sliceTimes removeObjectAtIndex:selectedRow];
[self.sliceTable reloadData];
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Clear NSTableView Content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18602210/clear-nstableview-content)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your NSTableViewDataSource numberOfRowsInTableView returns 0, the table will become empty.

Therefore, you can just clear your view model, and reload the table:

```
[self.sliceTimes removeAllObjects];
[self.sliceTable reloadData];
```

This is without animation. If you need the animation, include all row indexes in your NSIndexSet, and do the updates between beginUpdates/endUpdates (see https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nstableview/1527288-beginupdates?language=objc ):

```
NSIndexSet *removalSet = [NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndexesInRange:NSMakeRange(0, self.sliceTimes.count)];
[self.sliceTable beginUpdates];
[self.sliceTable removeRowsAtIndexes:removalSet withAnimation:NSTableViewAnimationSlideUp];
[self.sliceTimes removeAllObjects];
[self.sliceTable endUpdates];
```

Comment: nailed it! i was missing the reset with [self.sliceTable reloadData];
 Thank you